# Why do I get a redundant % (percent sign) when I run Java code in VSCode?

Tags: java, zsh, visual-studio-code

When I use Java in VSCode, I get an extra `%` in the output, like this:

[image: output ends with %]

but I didn't input `%`

My env:

- java version "1.8.0_201"
- javac 1.8.0_201
- zsh

My code:

```java
    class Shuffle1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int x = 3;
        if (x > 2) {
            System.out.print("a");
        }
        while (x > 0) {
            System.out.print("-");
            x = x - 1;
            if (x == 2) {
                System.out.print("b c");
             }
             if (x == 1) {
                System.out.print("d");
                x = x - 1;
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Running the code in the question in Visual Studio Code with the Code Runner extension gives the correct console output.

Comment: **Reviewers** This question has nothing to do with Java. The problem is with the Visual Studio Code interface, not the Java code, therefore this question is **on topic**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code in the question in Visual Studio Code with the *Code Runner* extension gives the correct console output:

```
a-b c-d
```

To run Java code with Code Runner, save Shuffle1.java by selecting *File* -> *Save*, and click the ▶ icon in the upper right corner of the code pane. When you hover the mouse over the ▶ icon a tooltip pops up which says *Run Code (Ctrl+Alt+N)*. The output will be shown in the console pane which is located immediately below the code pane.

[image: code pane in Visual Studio Code]
<sup>**code pane and console in Visual Studio Code**</sup>

Running Java code with Code Runner in Visual Studio Code is more convenient than running the same code in the terminal because I can debug the Java code from Visual Studio code using the Debugger for Java extension which I also have installed. I can also run the Java code by itself by clicking the ▶ icon without having to create a project for it first. For example when I'm trying a code block from Stack Overflow I usually don't want to create a whole project for it, because I want to try multiple code blocks and throw most of them away after trying them once. I don't even want to create a project for the best code block. Instead I want to save that code in a text file. This Java programming workflow does not create a separate project unless I need one.